# Cannot read property '<property name>' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I don't know what's wrong with my code.
The console logs are fine, but there is an error `Cannot read property 'aqua' of undefined` at the page.

**home.ts**

```
export class Home implements {
  color: any;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      this.color = data;
      console.log(this.color.aqua); //this logs fine
    });
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
{{color.aqua}} <!-- this produce error -->
```

Comment: `{{ color?.aqua }}`

Comment: The `color` variable is defined asynchronously, after the view is first displayed.  You should use `{{color?.aqua}}` to prevent the error.

Comment: Please, show us your JSON, cuz your attribute color looks like undefined.

Comment: @ConnorsFan please upgrade you comment to an answer so that I can accept it as an answer. The tutorial I am referring to doesn't mention the elvis operator :(

Comment: Jason White has posted an answer that you can accept. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is rendered before you get the response from you `GET` Request (Async)

You can use the elvis operator in this case

`{{ color?.aqua }}`

Alternatively you can use an `*ngIf`

```
<span *ngIf="color">{{ color.aqua }}</span>
```

---

#### Edit

As @ConnorsFan mentioned in the comments.  Using `<ng-container>` instead of a `<span>` will prevent and extra element from being rendered (`<span>`).

```
<ng-container *ngIf="color">{{ color.aqua }}</ng-container>
```

Comment: To avoid creating an extra element, you can use `ng-container` instead of `span`.

Comment: 7 minutes before eligible to accept as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A http request is async therefore the variable is initally undefined, so you need to show the variable only if it has a value, one way to do this would be using the following syntax: 
 `{{ color?.aqua }}` 
or

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="color && color.aqua">{{color.aqua}}</ng-template>
```

*Note, the second statement (color.aqua) is optional, but keep in mind a value which is undefined will not be shown in the template*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can only accept one answer. So I upvoted your answer too.